# Запрос с сортировкой по связанной таблице

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

В БД две таблицы со связью один ко многим: `Articles` -> `Parts`

Модель `Article.php`

```
public function scopePublished($query)
{
    $query->where('posted_at', '<=', Carbon::now());
}

public function scopeNewest($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('posted_at', 'desc');
}

public function parts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Part');
}
```

Модель `Part.php`

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
}
```

Логика в том, что у `Article` может быть множество дополнений `Parts`. Например, у какого-то события с ходом времени появляются дополнительные данные-дополнения. И эти дополнения составляют хронологию события (`Parts`).

Например, публикуется `Article` с информацией о предстоящих соревнованиях. Спустя какое-то время появляются результаты соревнований. Спустя ещё время - фотографии. А ещё спустя какое-то время что-то ещё. Обновлять один пост всей этой информацией не нужно - это составные части.

`Article` имеет поле `posted_at`. `Part` также имеет поле `posted_at`.

Как получить все опубликованные записи с их частями (которых может не быть), отсортировав все эти записи по времени публикации последней `Part`?

Т.е. нужно вывести все `Article`, отсортировав по времени публикации последних частей. Иначе говоря - первым в списке должна быть или самая новая статья (`Article`) или статья у которой есть самая новая часть (`Part`).

Как тут быть?

Запрос на получение постов и их частей такой

```
$news = Article::with('parts')
    ->published()
    ->newest()
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно в запросе использовать

```
Article::with(['parts' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}])
->published()
->newest()
->get();
```

Comment: Так не будет работать же. Мне ведь нужно отсортировать все Articles по posted_at Parts. А этот запрос сортирует просто Articles по его собственному полю posted_at. И сортирует отдельно связанные данные.